# Play Framework 2.3 - Does not detect changes

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3, typesafe-activator

Whenever I make a change on my Play app, it doesn't re-compile (auto-reload?) the changes and when I refresh the page I see the old version of the app. I have to `Control + D` every time I make a change to the source code, and that's not convenient.

I tried it on old apps, created new app, `activator clean`, `activator ~ run` ... doesn't help

...any ideas?

Comment: Some discussion of the issue: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/3703

Comment: @RichDougherty - thanks, i've looked into that and it seems to be working for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it to work using [this](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/3608#issuecomment-64729539) answer to an issue submitted on Github

> The simplest workaround is to use polling instead, by adding the following to your build:
>
> `PlayKeys.playWatchService := play.sbtplugin.run.PlayWatchService.sbt(pollInterval.value)`
>
> Note that I would not use this in combination with `~run`, because it will mean that Play and sbt will both be polling for changes in 2 separate threads, which is going to chew up a lot of cpu. Rather, just use it with `run`.